# Use adb over wi-fi with device that can't connect to computer

Tags: android, adb, android-wifi

My Nexus X has gone haywire and now refuses to connect to my computer.
Uninstalling and reinstalling all the drivers did nothing. 
A factory reset of the tablet also failed to help.

So, I am looking to use wi-fi debug but, of course, I can't connect to it to set the debug port to 5555.
Is there any way of setting it from the device rather than from the computer?

Comment: You have to be rooted to use the adb over wifi without a physical connection.
Also, you have to use a physical connection to root. Usually.
I had a similar problem with an old phone and I've been able to root it using kingroot. It's a chinese app, not so safe, that you can only install from an apk (google it). But I think it's the only option.

So, the only thing I can suggest you is: download kingroot -> Hope it will work -> root -> download adb over wifi from the playstore -> use it.

Comment: If I do root it (there are loads of "root"ers out there) how to I then set the port on the device?

Comment: I use this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=it

It work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a plugin to connect your device to your computer over WiFi but your device has to be connected at least once. Take a look https://github.com/pedrovgs/AndroidWiFiADB. Your phone hasn't to be rooted.

Comment: How can i use it? When i connect my device, press the button, it shows "Device connected" but when i disconnect the USB cable, my device disappear from the deployment targets.. When i press the button again, it writes "no connected devices"... same problem i had via my terminal... I connected over wifi to that device ONLY when it were connected via USB.... :/ thanks for advice